# Azure Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL flexibleServers database collations

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-database-postgresql

I tried to create new database with different (than en_US.utf8) collation on Azure Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL flexibleServers. CLI and Bicep gives "Internal Server Error" as a message and from Portal I cannot change the collation select input at all?
Is it really so that flexibleServers allow only en_US.utf8 collation or is there some properties that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

I tried creating azure database for PostgreSQL in Azure portal and I have not got the option to select the collation. Even when I tried to create new database, I cannot change character set and collation in portal.

[image]

- Therefore, I tried to create a new database using SQL command in Azure Data Studio.
- Connect postgreSQL server in Azure Data Studio. (Refer the MS document on [Connect and query PostgreSQL using Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/quickstart-postgres?view=sql-server-ver16) )
- Run this query to list the supported collation and encoding.
  `select  *  from pg_collation`
- Once connected, enter the following SQL script to create a new database with one of the supported collations from the above query.

```sql
CREATE  DATABASE  testdb  ENCODING='UTF8' LC_COLLATE='aa_DJ.utf8' TEMPLATE='template0';
```

- To check the collation of newly created Database, use the following query.

```sql
select datname,datcollate from pg_database;
```

[image]